# Grub rescue no such device

Tags: grubrescue

I tried to dual bolt win10 and ubuntu 15 and now it says grub rescue no such device: 906f6cfd-803q-4ac7-af57-896c9f334a5f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot into a Live CD/DVD/USB of ubuntu.

Then open up a terminal window. run these commands replace `/dev/sda` with your Drive name.

to find you drive name run this command

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

output of the command should look like this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250058268160 bytes, 488395055 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0009dcf3

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048 382078219 382076172 182.2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2  *    382078976 487346175 105267200  50.2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       487346176 488394751   1048576   512M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Where is says `Disk /dev/sda` at the start of the command that is your disk name. my disk name is  `/dev/sda` when you run the command below copy or type in your  device name  at the end of these commands

```
sudo grub-install
```

then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and then reboot.

Comment: Ok, I will update you when i have done it.

Comment: How do i switch dec/sda with my drive.

Comment: @NoahDuley sorry i didn't explain very well. i have edited by answer

Comment: I mean it works

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please don't forget to click the grey ☑ at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: I have 1 bigger problem

Comment: @NoahDuley if you have another problem ask another question.